# beautiful soup returns none when the element exists in browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have looked through the previous answers but none seemed to be applicable. I am building an open source quizlet scraper to extract all links from a class (e.g. https://quizlet.com/class/3675834/). In this case, the tag is a and class is "UILink". But when I use the following code, the list returned does not contain the element that I am looking for. Is it because of the JavaScript issue described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ac7buo/beautifulsoup4_find_all_returns_nothing_section/)?

I tried to use the previous method of importing folder as written [here](https://github.com/kelciour/improved-quizlet-to-anki-21-importer) but it does not contain the urls.

How can I scrape these urls?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"
}
url = 'https://quizlet.com/class/8536895/'

response = requests.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
b = soup.find_all("a", class_="UILink")
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to directly scrape dynamic webpages using just `requests`. What you see browser is fully rendered page taken care by browser.

Inorder to scrape data from these kind of webpages, you following any of below approaches.

1. Use `requests-html` instead of `requests`

   pip install requests-html

scraper.py

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

session = HTMLSession()

url = 'https://quizlet.com/class/8536895/' 

response = session.get(url)
response.html.render()  # render the webpage

# access html page source with html.html
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, 'html.parser') 

b = soup.find_all("a", class_="UILink")

print(len(b))
```

Note: this uses headless browser(chromium) under the hood to render the page. So it can timeout or be a little slow at times.

2. Use selenium webdriver

Use `driver.get(url)` to get the page and pass the page source to beautiful Soup with `driver.page_source`

Note: run this in headless mode as well and there might be some latency at times.